# Function onhide react-bootstrap-daterangepicket

Tags: reactjs

i am using this library to select date range. when I select a date range and press outside the selection box. it updates the date I clicked and displays them. I want only when I select the save function, the date will be updated and displayed. how to do it. thanks

I tried processing in the onhide function but it still updates the data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.